# what considered a critical code if preventive preemption is nowhere seen in the driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, network-driver

in realTek r8169 driver for ethernet it has poll function for polling interrupts which is New API(NAPI)

the rtl_rx called from poll function

either poll or nor rtl_rx do anything to disable kernel preemption except protecting DMA mapped pages got from `dma_map_page`  like

```
struct page *data;

data = alloc_pages_node(node, GFP_KERNEL, get_order(R8169_RX_BUF_SIZE));
if (!data)
    return NULL;

mapping = dma_map_page(d, data, 0, R8169_RX_BUF_SIZE, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
...
...
```

code

```
    dma_sync_single_for_cpu(d, addr, pkt_size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);

    ....
    dma_sync_single_for_device(d, addr, pkt_size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
```

I was under the impression that in even NAPI poll interrupts or interrupt handler we need to disable preemption.

And nowhere in code of the driver contains calls like `preempt_disable` or get_cpu or semaphores. So I like to know what considered a critical code in kernel driver? can anyone please tell me this and can interrupt be preempted? or in kernel in general

or can anyone point me to specific code in the driver

Comment: "I was under the impression that in even NAPI poll interrupts or interrupt handler we need to disable preemption." - Interrupts (both hardware and software) **implies** disabled preemption. And yes, NAPI's `poll` is called in softirq context.

Comment: @Tsyvarev can u give me example where critical code is protected with functions and methods or other methods also I specified in my question to preventing preempt behavior

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment. Because `poll` is called in softirq context, preemption is disabled during this call. So there is no needs to call `preempt_disable` from the `poll` method.